# How to copy unique data in their related Word path using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a cell to its related Word doc. I have all Word paths and their related text in the cell next to it, which needs to be copied to its related Word doc.

I wrote code that copies a cell to the open docs table, but I want it to be automated and open the first path and copy the related cell to that.

```vb
Sub copy()

Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim col As Long, r As Long
Dim wordApp As Word.Application

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

col = 1 'start with this column

r = 2 ' row

For Each v In rng.Cells
    ActiveDocument.Tables(13).Cell(r, col).Range.Text = v.Value
    col = col + 1
Next v

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveDocument is an element of a sample of wordApp
So, seems to be

```
 wordApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(13).Cell(r, col).Range.Text = v.Value
```

Or the problem is that it need to add columns in Tables(13)?

Comment: The problem is the automation and how to to connect the path with its related word doc. i wanted to open each doc, select the cell to be copied then copy to table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't got any wordApp object
You declare the variable as application, but don't use it. See code below:

```
Sub copy() 


Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim col As Long, r As Long
Dim wApp As Object' create an object for application object
Dim wDoc As New Word.Document' set object for Word document
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")' creates a sample of application object
wApp.Visible = True ' you can swith it to False if you don't need to see application

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

col = 1 'start with this column

r = 2 ' row

wApp.Documents.Open Filename:="Filename" ' "Filename"= name of your word file. Here you open it. 
Set wDoc = GetObject("Filename")' here you link your word document to word document object: after this you have two samples of objects - application object and document object 

For Each v In rng.Cells
wApp.wDoc.Tables(13).Cell(r, col).Range.Text = v.Value
col = col + 1

Next v

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I have linked this to a cell with a doc path in it. It opens but I get this error and it doesn't copy the value to the table. Run time error: Automation error, Invalid Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - make sure that your rng range is not empty

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim col As Long, r As Long
Dim wApp As Object
Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wApp.Visible = True ' you can swith it to False
Dim wDoc As New Word.Document
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

col = 1 'start with this column

r = 2 ' row

wApp.Documents.Open Filename:="C:\Users\shevti\Downloads\1.docx" ' your word file
Set wDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\shevti\Downloads\1.docx")

For Each v In rng.Cells


wDoc.Tables(13).Cell(r, col).Range.Text = v.Value
col = col + 1

Next v

End Sub
```